# How to back out certain pushes

Tags: git, git-revert

I'm looking at the last 10 or so pushes, and I would like to back out 4 of them (unconsecutive).

How can I do this?

In SVN, it would be a matter of reverting the changes and pushing the "undone" changes back in. Not sure how to do it in Git.

Comment: A search for "git revert" wasn't sufficient?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You use `git revert <commit>` to revert the offending commits without rewriting history. This creates a new commit that undoes these commits.

Instead of `<commit>` you use the SHA of each commit you want to revert.

Comment: Ultimately, this turned out to be best option. Tried "interactive rebase" but I had to do a lot more merging. Reverting the "bad" checkins turned out to be easiest. Realized that after merging, one has to add/commit/push the resolved file if there were conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

@ThiefMaster's answer works great.

As an alternative, **if it's not a shared remote branch** (meaning if no one else has pulled your changes) you could `git rebase -i HEAD~10`. This will open a list of the last 10 commits in your $EDITOR. Just delete the commits you no longer want, save the file, and `git push -f` to force push and overwrite the history on the remote branch.

Advantage: it's leaves the history cleaner.

Disadvantage: you might *not* want the history cleaned up and could desire having the revert commits captured in the git history.

More on interactive rebasing here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Changing-Multiple-Commit-Messages

Comment: I'd only do this as a last resort, since everyone else will need to rebase as a result.

Comment: Others would have to `git pull -f`. But yes, of course if it's a shared remote branch this is a luke warm idea. I thought I made that clear in the above that this was an alternative only to be done if it's not shared but I'll highlight that in bold. Advantage: it's leaves the history cleaner. Disadvantage: you might not want the history cleaned up and could desire having the revert commits captured in the git history. And again, the making all other devs do a force pull is a disadvantage.

Comment: The clarification of the pros and cons in the context of the other answer makes this option a helpful one, and there's less risk that the user will fall into a trap.